# how to parse a huge json file

Tags: android, json, gps

Hey guys im currently working on an app that will receive a vast amount of co-ordinates via a JSON file, the json file will look like the following:

{"posts":[{"Latitude":"53.4041999","lontitude":"-6.377542","Latitude":"53.4041999","lontitude":"-6.377542","Latitude":"53.4041999","lontitude":"-6.377542"}]}

Does anyone have any suggestions of how I could get the co-ordinates as double values ?

Answer (score 2):

Easier than `gson` and `Double.parseDouble()` use [getDouble()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getDouble%28java.lang.String%29) or [optDouble](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optDouble%28java.lang.String,%20double%29)().

Answer (score 1):

```
double myDouble = Double.parseDouble(theString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) that is a great library to work on json serialization and deserialization even into objects easily and fast